# Reliably query SPARQL endpoints and cache results locally

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

1. When we query LOD Cloud datasets (using SPARQL queries), we could face connection or server problems. Is there a reliable strategy that helps us to get data properly even in a such situations? I'm looking for a tool (in java) that helps to schedule querying tasks so that when an interruption occurs, the task will be re-run again until getting queried data.
2. I use Jena library to query remote SPARQL endpoints in order to retrieve LOD Cloud data and exploit it to do some stuff. Is there a mechanism to automatically cache returned data so when I re-query the dataset with same query, data is retrieved from local cache instead of remote dataset endpoint?

Comment: Me and my colleague implemented those things on top of Apache Jena, see [here](https://github.com/SmartDataAnalytics/jena-sparql-api)

Comment: @AKSW thank you.
I've already taken a look on that repository. It's a great work. However, I think it's not finished yet. There still an ingoing work to do; can you confirm ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not finished"? It's periodically updated for the latest Jena version. Retry, Caching, Proxy, Delegating, etc. are stable layers for years now.

Comment: I've see some TODOs in some project parts; this is what prevent me from using it.

Comment: hm, indeed it's an ongoing project, but afaik, the caching component and the retry part are stable and won't change in near future.

Comment: @Nasreddine, you could post the answer yourself, if AKSW's link looks good for you. This [example](https://github.com/SmartDataAnalytics/jena-sparql-api/blob/master/jena-sparql-api-core/src/main/java/org/aksw/jena_sparql_api/example/Example.java) seems to be exhaustive...

Comment: @StanislavKralin I'm facing some issues with provided example. Once I solve it I'll put an answer. Thanks.